# Is requestMapping needed for each page in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I read a big part of spring documentation, and I think that I missed this part.

Do I need requestMapping for each page in my webapp? Even for those static ones? For example if I have a page with few sites:
home
about me
contact
articles
SomeStaticPage

Do i need requestMapping in my controller for all of those pages? 
For example if I want to go to the contact page, I have to add requestMapping for path /contact in my controller ? Or if I will have contact.jsp in my /WEB-INF/views, Spring will detect it automaticly without defining RequestMapping for it?

Or maybe in href property I should just add static path to /contact.jsp ?

Also, I am aware of that, if for example for articles page, I will want to have articles taken from database, I will have to add request mapping which will put that article list object in Model object. 
I'm asking mainly for static pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or if I will have contact.jsp in my /WEB-INF/views, Spring will detect it automaticly without defining RequestMapping for it

I don't think that Spring can do that for you. And you can't access anything that is in WEB-INF directly via URL either.

What you could do is this:

**1:** Place the pages (HTML, JSP, ...) you want to access directly (without creating controllers for them) for example in `src/main/webapp/pages` (this location assumes that you are using Maven) and configure Spring to serve these pages directly.

You could do this using this XML configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="/pages/" />
```

**2:** you could use `<mvc:view-controller />` tag in your Spring configuration to define mappings for your views. In this case you would still have to define mappings for each view as with `@RequestMapping`, but in this case it is just a single line of code.

Additional benefit of this solution is that you could keep your URLs consistent with the rest of the application.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />
```

Java configuration alternatives to both examples are in the documentation mentioned below.

**Sources and additional information**

- [Configuring view controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller)
- [Configuring static resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)